# How to incorporate CSS into a table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to put CSS code into my table but don't want to styles at every row of the table. I have the following code:

#### CSS:

```
.statetable th
{
    width: 250px;
    color: red;
    text-align: left;
}
.statetable tr
{
    width: 250px;
}
```

#### JavaScript:

```
function showState()
{       
    myTable = "<table class='statetable'><br><th><td>Type</td>";
    myTable += "<td>Value</td></th>";

    createRow("------------------", "------------");
    createRow("Layout", (document.getElementById("startradio").form.format == "Default"));
    myTable +="</table>";
    document.getElementById("tableHolder").innerHTML = myTable;
}

function createRow(type, value)
{
    myTable += "<table class='statetable'><tr><td>" + type + "</td>";
    myTable += "<td>" + value + "</td></tr>";
}
```

#### HTML:

```
 <input type="button" id="button" value="Click to show states" onclick="showState()"/>
 <div id="tableHolder"></div>
```

The style is not working though. I have placed my th and tr's and placed the css with them but I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

Comment: you cant create `td` inside `th`

Comment: ... or use a `<br>` tag inside a `<table>` tag.

Comment: do you even need a table for this. `div`s might be easier in more ways than one.

Comment: @Novocaine: One can still use tables for tabular data.

Comment: @Cerbrus, correction: one *should* still use tables for tabular data

Comment: @RyanB: You're right :-)

Comment: @Cerbrus agreed, this to me just doesn't warrant a table. Just my opinion, but I don't think 2 columns is enough to use a table, even if it is tabular data. The `CSS` ball ache that tables present isn't worth it.

Comment: What about the _"The CSS ball ache"_ that divs present to get them to behave as a table? It's just a simple table. Use a CSS reset, then style it properly.

Comment: @Novocaine if you want to use CSS that's fine, but to make it accessible you must use WAI-ARIA roles, I think 4 or 5 are needed to do it correctly. Then again the prime rule of ARIA says you should use native elements/controls whenever possible.

Comment: Just my personal preference. I find it less work to use divs when there's only a few columns. Especially when it comes to responsive styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace these:

```
myTable = "<table class='statetable'><br><th><td>Type</td>";
myTable += "<td>Value</td></th>";
```

With these:

```
myTable = "<table class='statetable'><tr><th>Type</th>";
myTable += "<th>Value</th></tr>";
```

Also, in `createRow`, replace:

```
myTable += "<table class='statetable'><tr><td>" + type + "</td>";
myTable += "<td>" + value + "</td></tr>";
```

With:

```
myTable += "<tr><td>" + type + "</td><td>" + value + "</td></tr>";
```

Comment: In addition, he's opening a new `<table class="statetable">` each time he calls `createRow`.

Comment: ...wat. Editing answer, @Blazemonger.

Answer (score 0):

You are ending up with more starting `<table>` tags then closing ones.  The `createRow()` method should not return a starting `<table>` tag.

Also, `.set` width on the table instead of the `<tr>`/`<th>`.